# winApi работа со static

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Создать приложение в котором пользователь может динамически создавать статики.
Нажатие левой кнопки мышки определяет координаты x и y статика, после отпускания
кнопки определяется ширина и высота статика.
На статике отображается текст - номер статика.
Нельзя создать статик меньше 10х10 пикселей.

Очень сильно нужна помощь, не могу справиться (

Comment: статик это просто текстовая метка?

Answer (score 0):

Поищи в поиске по "making a game on c from scratch ep01 dan zaidan". В видео бразилец буквально шаг за шагом рассказывает как на Си с Win32api создать окно, буфер с графикой, как её отрисовывать, определять нажатые клавиши, читать позицию курсора...короче, всё что нужно. Разобраться можно легко и под свои нужды адаптировать код.
Твои "статики" можно хранить в динамической структуре данных - односвязном списке. Тоже погугли, как его реализовать в Си.